# How do I change the label/text of "Cash on Delivery" in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, payment-method

I want to change the text label from "Cash on Delivery" to "Pay Cash in Person", but I can't figure out how to target a hook and make these changes. I know that I should be targeting the 'default' within 'title' => array(), but not sure how to go about this.

```
    $this->form_fields = array(
        'enabled' => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce' ),
            'label'       => __( 'Enable cash on delivery', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'        => 'checkbox',
            'description' => '',
            'default'     => 'no',
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'Payment method description that the customer will see on your checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default'     => __( 'Cash on delivery', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'        => 'textarea',
            'description' => __( 'Payment method description that the customer will see on your website.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default'     => __( 'Pay with cash upon delivery.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
```

Comment: You can do it directly in WC Settings > Checkout > Cash on delivery > Title *(field)* … No need of code

Answer (score 0):

Go to wooCommerce -> Settings --> Payment Tab --> Cash on delivery click Manage and change title, text whatever you want.

[image]